# Command line arguments: use of space between program argument, and the argument's argument

Tags: c, arguments

Here, i have a program, which takes arguments (how surprising...). I want him to have several arguments, as:

```
./myprogram -f filename.txt -x -o
```

so i want main args with "-", and these arg shall accept an other arg, in the example, a filename.

I have this structure, very simple:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Program name: %s\n", argv[0]);

    while ((argc > 1) && (argv[1][0] == '-'))
    {
        switch (argv[1][1])
        {
            case 'f':
                printf("%s\n",&argv[1][3]);
                break;

            case 'd':
                printf("%s\n",&argv[1][2]);
                printf("%s\n",&argv[1][2]);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Wrong Argument: %s\n", argv[1]);
                usage();
        }

        ++argv;
        --argc;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, in case of -d, this prints what's following the argument, without space; here is a sample output:

```
./myprogram -dfilename
Program name: myprogram
filename
filename
```

and with the -f parameter,

```
./myprogram -f filename
Program name: myprogram
ffilename
```

it prints twice the first letter, and i don't understand why.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`argv` contains an array of strings. Argv[0] contains the program name, argv[1] contains `-f` in your case, argv[2] contains `filename`. If you print argv[1][3], you are printing the string starting at the *third letter* of `-f`. There is no such thing, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Mhh... okay, but then should not i fix a certain order in arguments, e.g. force the user to use some arguments before others?

Comment: Araelle: You should not enforce a certain order to the switches and arguments except for those which follow the common UNIX/Linux conventions.  If you do so then your program(s) will be more difficult to use.  There are standard library modules which provide option parsing which conforms to the conventions that are implemented by most UNIX/Linux command line programs.  You should read http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html and use it or a similar library unless you have extraordinary requirements that preclude doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a standard argument library, such as GNU getopt.

The problem with your code is that -f should be printing argv[2][0], not argv[1][3].  It also needs to check that argc is > 2.

Comment: `getopt` is actually a standard part of POSIX. If you want the extended GNU functionality (support for options after non-option arguments or long `--` options) then you should copy GNU `getopt.c` into your project and use it.

Also, some people (myself included) find the `getopt` style API clumsy and inefficient. You might be better off making your own API which takes a structure describing which characters are valid, whether they take arguments or just act as flags, and where to store the results.